# Unity создание круга с регулируемым размером окружности

Tags: c#, unity3d, изображения, ui

Ситуация такая,нужен круг (Image, так как это будет в Канвасе),что бы можно было регулировать размер краев круга(жирность), пробовал сделать через Mask - не подходит из-за того,что перекрывает задний фон.
    Желательно что бы все это происходило на одном объекте, без создание дочерних.
Пробовал через Sliced, но там размер краев круга статичный,какой спрайт положишь такой размер и будет

Comment: попробуйте добавить компонент Outline и поиграть с его параметрами

Comment: Через шейдер элементарно реализуется

Comment: А можешь пожалуйста показать как)

Comment: А можно вообще просто сделать 2 круга разного цвета и менять размер заднего